# How to capture FastForward media keys on audio/video element

Tags: javascript

Thanks to media key support in Browsers (like chrome), it is possible to play/pause an  element using the media keys on your keyboard (or mobile OS).

**How do sites like YouTube react to the fastforward/backward keys?**

I have not been able to find any documentation on detecting/reacting to those buttons. But it has to be possible, because YouTube (and I think other sites) do it too. Trying to read the JS there is undoable, unfortunately.

Example:

- Open any PlayList on YouTube (example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abX559xa9gA&list=PLZhjR9_8QJZs5QA8qi5f2YcYcpl0rgWvd )
- Start the video.
- Press play/pause media key on your keyboard. -> The video reacts.
- Press fastfoward media key on your keyboard. -> The next video plays. **How is YouTube doing this?**

---

Answer has been given, although I recommend setting all 4, because on mobile devices "seek" works, on desktop only "next" works.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved through [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API).

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
```

Comment: Almost, on Android/iOS it will work with just seekbackward/seekforward. However, on desktop only previoustrack/nexttrack

I would recommend setting all 4.
````